# Laravel limit relation data

Tags: laravel

I have the following eloquent query:

```
$move['topUsers'] = UserMoves::where('move_id',$move->id)
                ->with(array('userBase'=>function($query){
                    $query->select('id','name')->orderBy('power','desc')->take(3);
                    }))->get();
```

The query works fine but the `->take(3)` doesn't. I get all of the relation results while I'm looking only for the first 3, ordered by `power` column.

the `->orderBy('power','desc')->take(3)` is not working in the `$query`.

How I can limit the realtion data to 3 results ordered by the `power` column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try method from [this article](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/) which is exactly about limiting relationship while eager loading:

```
// New relationship
public function mostPowerful()
{
    return $this->hasOne('userBase')->orderBy('power', 'desc');
}

// Get data
$move['topUsers'] = UserMoves::where('move_id',$move->id)
                             ->with('mostPowerful')
                             ->take(3)
                             ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$move['topUsers'] = DB::table('your_table_name')
                ->where('move_id', $move->id)
                ->select('id','name','power')
                ->orderBy('power', 'desc')
                ->take(3)
                ->get();
```

Hope this work.

Answer (score 0):

Without array:

```
$topusers = UserMoves::where('move_id',$move->id)
                     ->with(['userBase'=>function($query){
                            $query->select('id','name')->orderBy('power','desc')->take(3);
                        }])->get();
```